# How to prevent jQuery mobile's automatic page styling?

Tags: jquery-mobile

jQuery mobile automatically adds classes to all elements on my page on loading... this really messes up the jQuery UI widgets I have on the page. Is there any way to prevent jQuery mobile from automatically adding classes to my HTML elements? I only wan't some of the jQuery mobile widgets on my page, and I want to specify them explicitly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can ask jquery mobile not to touch your widget by putting the attribute below:

```
data-role="none"
```

Comment: That works. In addition, to this answer if you want to disable the mobile for the whole page you can use $.mobile.autoInitializePage = false; in the mobileinit event... read documentation peps.

Comment: I don't like this answer because I have many data-role="button" that I DO WANT to be buttons, but I do NOT want jqm to mess with them until they are needed, because currently jqm is styling 100 buttons during load phase. ... ... ... So for me I want to be able to leave data-role="button" BUT THEN BE able to append some other 'don't touch now' directive onto the html element.