# How to prevent jquery mobile adding it's classes to html elements?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I develop drag'n'drop jquery mobile constructor. When jmobile core loaded it's override my css rules by adding some classes to different elements. How prevent this? 
I want apply transform after element dropped on my "canvas". How can I do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Perhaps adding data-role="none" as attribute will help?

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc2/docs/forms/forms-all-native.html

Comment: I know about data-role="none", but which place I should add it?

Comment: "Adding the data-role="none" attribute to any form or button element tells the framework to not apply any enhanced styles or scripting. "

Quoted from the jquermobile.com site link above.

Comment: Add this attr to **each** element? Oh my God. I try add this attr to <html>, but jmobile add his class "ui-mobile"

Comment: They solved that here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8959519/how-to-prevent-jquery-mobiles-automatic-page-styling

Comment: I read it. When I using $.mobile.autoInitializePage = false; there are 5 seconds when page not visible (white screen) and after that, html get "ui-mobile" class

Comment: I don't like this answer because I have many data-role="button" that I DO WANT to be buttons, but I do NOT want jqm to mess with them until they are needed, because currently jqm is styling 100 buttons during load phase. ... ... ... So for me I want to be able to leave data-role="button" BUT THEN BE able to append some other 'don't touch now' directive onto the html element.