# Go to anchor link on click event jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink, anchor

As the descriptions says, I've found many things about smooth scrolling and the location property on java script but nothing seems to do what Im looking for which is simply imitate the function of a html "a" tag (I need to NOT use the html link tag for this project)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make JQuery take the user to a different URL than the page (like an anchor tag) attach window.location to the event.

For example, this:

```
$('#ClickMe').click(function(){ window.location = 'index.php'; });
```

Would take the user to index.php if he clicks on the element that has the ID "ClickMe" (E.G. ...

Comment: Hah, I misread the question I think. For some reason I thought he meant just jumping to a name tag on the same page.

Answer (score 6):

So what i get is you want to scroll down to an element without using html anchor tag
If i am right 
Assuming you have a html input tag

```
<input type="button" id="top" value="button"/>
```

this script will do the work

P.S #bottom_id is the id of element you want to scroll to.
or anchor link:

```
<a href="#bottom" id="bottom_id"></a>
```

script:

```
 $("#top").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#bottom_id").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The jquery way:

```
$("body").scrollTop($("[name=elementname]").position().top)
```

This gets the top of the named element and sets the scroll top position to that location.

There is a jquery [plug in](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) which does this effectively, but if you want to stick to straight javascript you can just use element.scrollTo as described on [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481350/how-to-get-scrollbar-position-with-javascript);

Better documentation for this can be found on [Mozilla's site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop). With javascript.

Comment: Jquery would be way more convenient and T think using "scrollTo" is a clever way to do it as in the plug in, if there is no other way to do it, I think i will do it like that, but I was hoping there would be another way, something like an already defined function that would do the trick, maybe the goToURL() function but thank you, this is helpful of course

Comment: I added some flavor to the answer using an example. Not a built in method, but simple enough.