# Using a tag in a dynamic url

Tags: html

I'm struggling to get the contact ref to work from different pages.
Basically for every product a different detail reference is provided (see 4867820 below).

I would like to create a button which links to the #contact id for every page on the website.

Basically if I put a link on the button including the reference, this works perfectly.

http://www.mywebsite/product/4867820#contact

However I am wondering if I can create something similar where the button links to the contact id on the same page without using the reference number.

http://www.mywebsite/product/*this page*#contact

So basically my question is how do I link to only #contact on this page without the reference numbers, so I can create 1 button on the page template.

Regards,

Comment: Do you link to the same page that the button is on?

Comment: you need to use something like `php` to store that referce number inside a variable , this can be done in the session or on database level. If you have a variable its pretty easy : `http://www.mywebsite/product/ . $product->id . #contact`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it will always point to the same page as the button:

a) If you are able to use anchor tags instead of buttons (and CSS-style them to look like buttons), you can simply point the anchor's href attribute to the section name.

It works like a relative link, just appending the href to current URL. Like so:

```
<a href="#contact">Contact Here</a>
```

Or b) if you have to use only a `<button>` or `<input>` element specifically, you will need to use javascript to set the location in onclick handler of the button. For details on that see: [Javascript inline onclick goto local anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11815295/javascript-inline-onclick-goto-local-anchor)